# Spring Security requiring login at every request

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, spring-security

I feel like the default behaviour of persisting a successful login has changed in Spring Security.

My security config:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)
        throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authReg -> authReg
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            // without this I need to login at every request
            .sessionManagement(sess -> sess
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            )
            .httpBasic(
                    Customizer.withDefaults()
            )
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable); // DEV ONLY
    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

Why would I need to specify the session-creation-policy now to achieve the effect of not having to log in every time, thus using an established session.

Especially since the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html) tell me "This is done automatically by default, so no additional code is necessary".

Spring Boot 3.2.2, Spring Security 6.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of the documentation might explain the behavior you are facing:

[Configuring Persistence for Stateless Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#stateless-authentication)

> Some authentication mechanisms like HTTP Basic are stateless and,
> therefore, re-authenticates the user on every request.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Maybe it has always been like that and I just confused FormBased and BasicAuth in previous attempts...

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Security 6, the default is that authentication mechanisms themselves must invoke the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`. This means that there is no need to detect when `Authentication` is done and thus the `HttpSession` does not need to be read for every request.See [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#moving-away-from-sessionmanagementfilter)